# PANDAS installation issues

Tags: installation, pandas

Please bear with me as I'm a beginner python user and I have seen the other posts on this topic, but am still encountering the same problems.

I'm trying to install pandas on my mac (currently running python 2.7.3) but keep getting this error message both in the notebook and IDLE:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
   import pandas
   ImportError: No module named pandas
```

I installed pandas and the relevant dependencies using MacPorts. I've seen that having two versions of python could be causing this, but after checking, I'm only running one version.

Could anyone help me out on this? Its a bit frustrating...

Comment: Would you mind posting what `port info py27-pandas` returns?

Comment: It's better that use [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/) to create the new environment, and then use `pip` to install pandas.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that pandas is not in the right directory/folder. 
Where is the pandas folder on your machine ? On my Windows machine, it's in the Python27\Lib\site-packages folder. There is likely a similar folder on the Mac. Copy and drag the pandas folder into there and then restart Python and see what happens.